# User input is splitted for while loop

Tags: c

I have a program that gets user input using `fgets`, but when the input has spaces it seems to be erratic.

So when I input File 1 and then press the enter key, this is the output

```
`FilePlease enter your file Name`
`1Please enter your file Name`
```

If I compare without spaces, it seems to work.

```
int MAX_NAME_SZ = 256;
char * fileName = malloc (MAX_NAME_SZ);

while (ValidateFileName(fileName) != 0)
{
    printf("Please enter your file Name\n");
    fgets (fileName, MAX_NAME_SZ, stdin);
} 

int ValidateFileName(char * fileName)
{
    printf(fileName);
    if  ((strcmp(fileName, "File 1") == 0) || (strcmp(fileName, "File 2") == 0) ||
         (strcmp(fileName, "File 3") == 0) || (strcmp(fileName, "File 4") == 0) ||
         (strcmp(fileName, "File 5") == 0))
         return 0;
     else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Calling `ValidateFilename()` on an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. Also adding `\n` to the `printf(filename)` might be useful.

Comment: you probably want to do `do { ... } while (ValidateFileName(fileName) != 0);`

Comment: @John3136, there's a `'\n'` in that because of its origin (`fgets` typically inserts that). This could be a problem.

Comment: @Seb You can tell I'm not using `fgets` these days ;-) It is certainly *A* problem since the `strcmp()`s don't have a `\n`...

Comment: Printing user entered strings like `printf(fileName)` is not a good idea, as `printf()` will try to handle format specifiers in the string.  Try `printf("%s", fileName)` or use a different function instead...

Comment: @John3136 Likewise; it's a tedious function to use properly, as it ivolves reallocation or truncation (discarding user input) when it fails to read the entirety of a line. I'd rather design my program around `argv`-based user input as that involves neither, or failing that read character by character as that seems to come out clearer when reallocating...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing "File 1" to "File 1\n".  Change your strcmp calls to strncmp calls, like this: `(strncmp(fileName, "File 1", strlen("File 1")) == 0)`

Comment: Not a very robust solution. How about when we get to "File 11" ? Part of the problem (see comments) is the '\n' chars that are in one string but not the other.

Comment: I think it's robust, but not extensible. :)  It would be better to implement a `chomp` style function to get rid of the trailing `\n`, but I thought this would be the quickest solution for the OP.